# How do I display multiple images onto one images in HTML

Tags: html

I want to use HTML and display one large image. 
On this large image I then wish to display multiple smaller images, all on different places and sizes.

I would prefer doing this using HTML only.
But, if this is not possible, Javascript or something like that is also an option...  :-)
If anybody has any idea using PHP, that would also be great.

I have search the web and StackOverflow, and tried MANY possible solutions, but none of them allowed me to display one big image, and then display multiple other images on top of this big image.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards,
Michael

Comment: Have you tried css and z-index + absolute positions?

Comment: if your problem is solved, please mark one of the replies as an answer. The tick mark corresponding the reply.

Answer (score 2):

you can use a container div which will contain all the smaller images. You can set background of that particular div.

your html as

```
<div id="container">

</div>
```

and css as follows:

```
div#container{

        background-image: url("image.jpg");
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        height:100%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot overlay an image over another image in pure HTML only, but what you CAN do is re-locate a image's position  onto another tag and just move it accordingly with css.

Comment: Are you suggesting CSS is not "pure" html? And absolute positioning an img is no problem.

Comment: ok, my bad, I was including CSS + HTML as one thing , but you're right, once you use CSS is not HTML neither

Answer (score 0):

Two alternatives:

1. defining the big image in as background using CSS, then you can put onto it whatever html markup you want to. Such backgorund can also be declared for elements like `div`s, not only for the whole page.
2. use absolut positioning inside your style definition. That way you can add big and small images to your markup and then position them on top of each other.

No javascript required for this and php has nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can position them as I have done in this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xxUpk/

The `top:-NNNpx` is crude, you could use `float` and many other ways of positioning them. Also look into `z-index` to layer them.